# ExtJs 7 (Community) npm build for Production Not Working

Tags: node.js, npm, extjs

I have an application on ExtJs 7.0.0-CE, it works well locally at *webpack-dev-server* running with *npm run dev*, but when I build as production and copy it to IIS doesn't.

I'm building using npm:

> npm run build

The result at output is:

[image]

What I had observed is that the URL I'm calling is "http://myserver/indicators", but the Ext tries to load using only the base URL "http://myserver/".

[image]

The browser console show :

> GET http://192.168.10.211/main.js?da2a6a29bf9e7731b19e net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

I think the get should include the virtual path, like:

> GET http://192.168.10.211/indicators/main.js?da2a6a29bf9e7731b19e

- **And the main.js doesn't even exists at the output folder of build**

Below I put some config files that may be relevant.

[app.json](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am5f8l1CeP6ag5x-Gnx8hanJKSTN_A?e=BXRTGJ)

[package.json](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am5f8l1CeP6ag5x_7que86yZzh94mA?e=ywwo9F)

[Application.js](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am5f8l1CeP6ag50AHixkR9z60iPQNw?e=4TpspH)

App.js:
`Ext.application({  extend: 'paineis.Application',  name: 'paineis'});`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was what I suspected, the base url without the virtual path.

The solution was to remove the tag `<base href="/">` from Index.html at the root folder of the application before build the application.

From:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head><base href="/">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
.
.
.
```

To:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html manifest="">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
.
.
.
```

With it removed, worked just fine and all files were found and application worked just fine!